# PHP variable results array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have the following code:

```
echo"<input  name=\"q". $i. "\" value=\"4\" id=\"q1a1\" type=\"radio\" ";
    if ($results['q1']==4) echo "checked"
    echo";
    />";
```

Edit:  Added the echo statement, which is why the `\` are in situ.

The part `$results['q1']` I'd like the `1` of the `'q1'` to be a variable - this doesn't seem to have the desired effect:

```
if ($results['q".$i."']==4) echo "checked"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you put the string and variable in *double quotes*, the whole thing is evaluated to 1 variable:

```
if ( $results["q$i"] == 4 ) echo "checked"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($results['q'.$i]==4) echo "checked"
```

this prevents issues with string interpolation.  Wouldn't really be an issue in this case, but I feel better staying away from it, as it makes code look dirtier to me.

Answer (score 0):

you want to write:

```
if ($results["q".$i]==4) echo "checked"
```

the "." operator will concatenate 2 strings to make a string and an associative array takes a string. Moreover variable inside ' (quote) operators won't be parsed (that's the difference between " and ') so '$i' will just give a string $i.

Answer (score 0):

ou can either do

```
 if ( $results["q".$i] == 4 ) echo "checked"; // .(dot) operator concatenates strings/variables.
```

or

```
 if ( $results["q$i"] == 4 ) echo "checked"; // double-quotes evaluates variables inside them.
```